# Map numbers in C language

Tags: c, dictionary

How can i map numbers like this:

```
1 => 0x01;
2 => 0x03;
3 => 0x07;
4 => 0x0F;
....
8 => 0xFF;
```

I have only 8 numbers to map and i need this for my RT embedded system so the solution must be efficient.
Is there a way to implement this using ENUM or DEFINE?
I don't want to use switch statement. Should i use an array:

```
BYTE bMap[8] = 
{
    0x01,
    0x03,
    0x07,
    0x0F,
    ....
    0xFF,
}
```

or is there another way?
Thank you! Max.

Comment: Why do you need to map them? What's the end goal?

Comment: How `3 => 0x07` in hex???

Comment: @Shan: map refers to a mathematical relation, not equivalent form.

Comment: @Mureinik I have a for loop, "i" represents the current iteration and i want to map the current "i" to the current mask...

Comment: @MaxZ Could you not just iterate 0-7 instead of 1-8?

Comment: 0x03 = 0000:0011; (mask)

Comment: An array, as you suggest yourself, is very efficient in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing *wrong* with using the lookup table to get your numbers but you *could* consider another approach.

If you're simply looping through those values in order, each one can be obtained by left-shifting the previous and setting the low order bit to 1:

```
      0000 0001 (x01)

<< 1: 0000 0010
 | 1: 0000 0011 (x03)

<< 1: 0000 0110
 | 1: 0000 0111 (x07)

<< 1: 0000 1110
 | 1: 0000 1111 (x0f)

<< 1: 0001 1110
 | 1: 0001 1111 (x1f)
```

So, something like:

```
for (unsigned int i = 1; i < 0x100; i = (i << 1) | 1) ...
```

should do the trick.

The only *possible* advantage I can see that *may* have would be not having to go out to memory for a lookup table. Depending on your hardware architecture, that may or may not be a problem.

The following complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 1; i < 0x100; i = (i << 1) | 1)
        printf ("%02x ", i);
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

shows it in action:

```
01 03 07 0f 1f 3f 7f ff
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will use this approach.

Answer (score 3):

The two most obvious solutions would be:

1. Use an array. `const uint8_t masks[] = { 1, 3, ... }`.
2. Your mask seems to be "the `i + 1` rightmost bits should be set", so you can trivally compute that at runtime using `(1 << (i + 1)) - 1` which is easier to implement and less error-prone.

Comment: His example map has `(i << i) - 1`

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 8 values and that's not going to change, use the array.  But note that the mapping would be `0=>0x01, 1=>0x03, ...` etc., because C indexing is zero-based.

Also, look for a pattern in your numbers: you could find a logic or arithmetic operation that will set the least significant N bits in a byte.  I.e.  N => (2 * N) -1